# how do I scale out Flink while sharing the same state?

Tags: apache-flink

The semantic of the workload is the following:

Flink operator reads events from the same Kafka topic. Each `event` needs to be processed by an expensive function `f` exactly once, ideally, if not  at least once. There is correlation between events so each event should be processed based on the cumulative `state` (accumulated by events from initial state).

How can we scale horizontally for this use case in Flink? I want to process events concurrently but all event processing depends on the same state. In my use case the size of the state will first climb to and then fluctuate around one terabyte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application needs to have a single, centralized data structure that is accessible to every event, then that application won't be horizontally scalable.

Flink approaches horizontal scaling by independently processing partitions of the data streams. This is usually done by computing a key from every event, and partitioning the stream around that key. State is maintained independently for each distinct key, and the limit to horizontal scaling is the number of distinct keys (the size of the key space). Rescaling is handled automatically, and is implemented by re-sharding the set of keys among the parallel instances.

Flink also supports non-keyed state, but the basic principle still applies: scaling can only be achieved by partitioning the stream, and maintaining state independently within each partition.

Comment: ```scaling can only be achieved by partitioning the stream, and maintaining state independently within each partition.

``` Thanks! Does that mean each parallel instance will read all events and then selectively process the event by key? Where and how does the re-sharding work?

Comment: No. Flink scales to clusters with thousands of nodes, with throughput measured in billions of events per second. If every instance had to touch every event that wouldn't be possible. Instead, the keyed partitions are each processing disjoint substreams. As for rescaling, that requires taking a global snapshot of the state of the cluster, and restarting the cluster from that snapshot.

Comment: ```keyed partitions are each processing disjoint substreams``` is this done from the message queue side or on the flink side? If on flink side, is it done by the job manager or dispatcher or where? I dont seem to find a way to read only selected events from AWS SQS.

Comment: This starts on the message queue side. Distributed logs that are designed for massive scale like Kinesis (and Kafka, Pulsar, etc) store topic shards on separate servers so that consumers can operate independently, and Flink leverages that. When Flink needs to re-partition the data, keyBy (and other related operations) can be used to cause a network shuffle wherein the workers exchange data among themselves.